# How do I set up emails on Spree Commerce?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, spree

So I know I can install the mailer gem from here:

https://guides.spreecommerce.com/user/configuring_mail_methods.html

But it clearly says that generic action mailer settings are more favourable at the top of the page.

I have installed postmark which is sending emails fine in an extension I built. However Spree does not appear to be sending emails when I create an order for a customer. How can I turn these transactional emails on without the Spree mailer gem, as I want to use postmark on its own.

Also where the hell is the listed email section from the documentation?

https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/deployment_tips.html

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up emails by adding the gem at https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings

Not sure if the message at the top of the page has been changed since this question was posted but it says to use that gem now.

Add `gem 'spree_mail_settings', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings'` to you gemfile and you will get a new page in the admin settings for setting up your email

[image]

Comment: For anyone visiting in 2019, that gem is broken, don't bother with it.

Comment: It's still broken in 2021

Comment: It's still broken in 19 July 2021

Comment: It's still broken in 09 April 2022

Answer (score 1):

An update for those facing this issue in 2021:

It's not recommended to use this gem. Instead, use a standard rails configuration: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration

This guide on how to fix extensions for Spree 4+ may also come in handy: https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/contributing/upgrading_extensions.html

If anyone is desperately in need of this extension, feel free to submit a pull request!